# html code to download on client side a file created by php on server side

Tags: php, html, post, download

User can upload a file with

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" ...
<input type="file"   name="file_post" ...
```

the file is loaded on server side

1. Production: `$_FILES[file_post][tmp_name] = /tmp/phpRGYt66`
2. Localhost: `$_FILES[file_post][tmp_name] = /opt/lampp/temp/phpRGYt66`

and processed by php. I create a new file appending ".csv" to the name of the input file with fopen and put content with fwrite

In localhost i am able to retreive the file `/opt/lampp/temp/phpRGYt66.csv` and ensure it is what i expect.

Then the user can downlaod the output file with

`<a href="<?php echo $csv_file_name; ?>">Download csv file</a>`

**This download does not work**

1. In localhost: when the mouse hoover the '<a' the browser displays `localhost/opt/lampp/temp/phpRGYt66.csv` and i get

```
Error 404
localhost
Apache/2.4.54 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1s PHP/8.2.0 mod_perl/2.0.12 Perl/v5.34.1
```

2. In Production:
   when the mouse hoover the '<a' the browser displays `mywebsite.fr/tmp/phpRGYt66.csv` and i get

```
Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.
```

With FileZilla i do not see any /tmp/ folder and i am not able to find the .csv file created.

How to solve this issue ?

Thanks

I try to download a temporary file managed by php with an html "<a href" but it does not work, neither in localhost, neither in production

Comment: can you please share the code for this `the file is loaded on server side`, also are you using absolute paths while creating CSV file?

Comment: How are you storing the file? can you show the code to manage the upload?

Comment: @Adi The file is uploaded with a html <form>, see the beginning of my question.
Then
$file = $_FILES["file_post"]["tmp_name"];
...
$csvfile = $file.'.csv';
$csv = fopen($csvfile, 'w+b');

Comment: _"I try to download a temporary file managed by php"_ - you need to move the file out of the temporary upload folder first of all. If you do not process a file upload in the script it was send to, then PHP will _remove_ that file again, when the script ends. Which it has long done, before you can click any links on the client side.

Comment: Using rename i succeed to move it and do what i want in production. But in localhost rename failed "acess denied". Looking to the right of /op/lampp/temp: full acces to 'daemon' not root, niether me. And i get 'operation not allowed' when i try to change the right.

Answer (score 2):

The server's file system and the web server's public directory are two different things.

This stores the file in this path relative to the root of the server's file system:

```
/opt/lampp/temp/phpRGYt66
```

So applications running on the server can read the server's file system and read the file.  But the *web server* doesn't see that file.

> Imagine for a moment what could/would happen if any user anywhere on the internet could read *any file* anywhere on your server.

You essentially have two options:

1. Store the file in the web server's public folder structure and give users that URL.
2. Store the file outside of the web server's public folder structure and write a PHP script which accepts the name of the file (or some other identifier) and prepends that name with the known location of the file and streams that file to the user.

**Be very careful** if you choose the second approach.  It may be tempting to just allow the user to send you the path of the file and then you send them whatever file they request.  But remember...

> Imagine for a moment what could/would happen if any user anywhere on the internet could read *any file* anywhere on your server.

Make sure you don't let the user download whatever file they want from your file system.  Keep files in a folder known only to your server-side code and only serve the user files from that folder.  (From a security perspective, the very nature of the question being asked strongly suggests that you should choose the first option above.)